# django error - ImportError: No module named apps

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a first django project called mysite. The structure of my project is:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        migrations/
           __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
```

I have created the database called sample. After modifying the models.py file. I'm trying to run the command- python manage.py makemigrations polls. but m getting the following error.

```
/Documents/mysite$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named apps
```

my settings.py file looks like this:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sample',
        'USER': 'lo',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                 
        'PORT': '3306', 
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Please help me to solve this. I'm novice to python. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because it is looking for an `apps` module inside of `PollsConfig`, you can just include `polls` in your installed apps

```
'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
```

should be

```
'polls',
```

Comment: The 'PollsConfig' comes from the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/), strangely...